# What is the purpose of the @function {} block and why do we need it

Tags: blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to understand the significance of the `@functions {}` block in blazor webassembly.  If I create a new blazor project in VS it looks like below out of the box.  We have a `@code` block.  But then in many blazor docs, I see `@functions{}`..what is the difference?  When should I use which?  Can I use them together?  Can I nest them together? When I see `{` and `}` I think of `scope` vars and objects.  Does `scope` has to do with it?  Why would I want to scope my vars in a razor page?  Thanks in advance.

[image: Out of the box template]

Comment: '@functions' is simply the old name for '@code' (from the earlier pre-release versions of Blazor).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the beginning, the `@functions {}` block directive which enables adding C# members (fields, properties, and methods) to the generated Blazor class was used. But then Steve Anderson and friends reached the conclusion that a new directive term should replace the `@functions {}` which is used in Razor Pages as well. After long debate in github, the `@code` term was chosen.

You should replace the `@functions` term with the `@code` term whenever you use old code. This is for consistency' sake only, as the term `@functions` is supported as well (perhaps for compatibility's sake). In short you can use either of the two without any issues. But one must not be a "smart boy" and use the `@functions` term so as to impress other how smart they are. The `@code` term has been successfully adopted by the community and that is how one should code.

One thing is important to remember: Do not use both terms in your Blazor apps. Be consistent.